How to get count of rows of table that is in dynamic variable in EF Core?
I have this code:
dynamic table = langaugeTypeToTableMapping[language][typeOfData];
int rowsQuantity = table.Count();

Here table is dynamic and it refers to one of tables (models), and all these tables have a Count() property, that works correctly.
But as soon as I call the Count() of the same table, but via the dynamic variable, I get this exception:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<KeyboardTrainer.Models.EnglishWord>' does not contain a definition for 'Count'

In short, this code works without exception:
int rowsQuantity = db.EnglishSongs.Count();

But not this one:
dynamic table = db.EnglishSongs;
int rowsQuantity = table.Count();

How can I get the number of rows of the table that a variable refers to if that table is different every time? And, finally, why do I get this exception at all? It looks broken.
PS: I don't want to use raw SQL here.
